# Why use https to connect aws load balancer with instances in vpc?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elb, vpc

Given the security features of Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) on Amazon aws such as private subnet and private ip addresses, is there any difference between using HTTPS and HTTP to connect backend instances with load balancer from security point of view? Given the security features of VPC, is HTTP still less secure than HTTPS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an entirely supported configuration, and is called SSL Termination / offloading.

By passing off the encryption process to load balancers you are lightening the load on your webservers.

Since all of your servers are in a VPC you're not losing any security, nobody (apart from AWS!) could eavesdrop on your traffic. So it makes sense to keep that in cleartext and let the load balancers take care of the security.

There is an AWS document here - [AWS Elastic Load Balancing: Support for SSL Termination](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-load-balancer-support-for-ssl-termination/)

Comment: Thanks! its clear now I do not have to use HTTPS between ELB and instances.

Comment: @user3005720 you don't have to use https internally. In fact, [NSA prefers you don't](http://techcrunch.com/2014/03/20/gmail-traffic-between-google-servers-now-encrypted-to-thwart-nsa-snooping/).